# Impact of removing VTP from a production network

Tags: cisco, switch, vtp, cisco-3750

We are planning to remove VTP from a production network that has RPVST running. This is at the core (a pair of Cisco 3750s) and we are trying to weigh the impact it has on the production network.

In theory, this should not effect anything, the VLANs are already in the switches' VLAN database and they would continue humming along.

This following is quoted from the Cisco 3560 configuration guide.

> Note: You can use the vtp mode transparent global configuration
>   command to disable VTP on the switch and then to change its VLAN
>   information without affecting the other switches in the VTP domain.

I may have answered own question above but the real question really is:

**Has anyone done this configuration before to test the theory above?**

Comment: Yes. As a precaution, set the VTP clients to transparent *first*, then the active server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In theory, you'll want to migrate the clients to transparent before you remove the server from the equation.  This makes absolute certain that things will continue to function without any gotchas.

In practice, it doesn't matter.  A server will just stop sending summary advertisements to the VTP domain and the clients will continue using the last seen revision.

We just went through this on one of our tiny, alternate networks.  Someone completely wiped out the VTP server and it went unnoticed for months before anyone looked.

Comment: This _'incident'_ is exactly why configuration accounting is such a big deal.

Answer (score -1):

Change to transparent mode will not affect the VLAN configuration in other switches in VTP domain.VTP advertisements still pass through the transparent mode switch.

Comment: The question is on the impact of changing VTP modes on a production network, not the theory behind it.